# Java - Running 7zip

Tags: java, process, runtime, 7zip

I have an application that uses 7zip in order to unzip a file. The code I use is the following:

```
Runtime prog = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = prog.exec(System.getenv("ProgramFiles").concat("\\7-Zip\\7z x " + "\""+path+"\""+ " -o"+Values.temp_path));

InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
InputStream instr = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
InputStreamReader insr = new InputStreamReader(instr);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(insr);
String line = null;
String line2 = null;

while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null & (line2 = br2.readLine()) != null){}

int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

Where path is the file's location and temp_path the location where it will be unzipped.

While this works fine in my computer, I have colleagues that get errors when they run this same app.

In my computer, the value of the variable exitVal is set to 0 by the method waitFor. In other computer I've seen this variable set to 1 (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION). The app is the same in both computers, both using win xp and the same version of 7zip, what else could I be missing?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I found the difference between the 2 computers. The one that works has java 7 installed, while the one with the issue has java 6

Comment: Why don't you use the 7-Zip [SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using zip files, you better take a look at [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html). This way you won't have to rely on a tool that may or may not be there.

If you're using .7z files (compressed with `LZMA`), there is a library named [lzmajio](https://github.com/league/lzmajio) that will also give you java Streams.

---

**Resources:**

- [contrapunctus.net: LZMA Streams in Java](http://contrapunctus.net/league/haques/lzmajio/)
- [7-zip SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)
- [oracle.com: Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)

Comment: I'm using 7-zip files, I'm looking at how to use 7-zip SDK, never done noyhing like this before :) Thanks!